# what is the best way to use less Django template syntax as possible with Django Form?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, frontend

I am just beginner of Django.

At first, It seemed very convenient to use Django Form. I can get all which i already I defined in Model with ModelForm class. I can just put { form } in template. There are already pre-defined Field type and I can use it conveniently.

But it is tricky if you need to work with one who doesn't know Django or Python and are charge of making front-end part.

For example, I make template like this.

example.html

```
<form action="." method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="ok">
```

views.py

```
class TestView(FormView):
    template_name = 'example.html'
    form_class = TestForm
    success_url = '/success/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('data is validated! you can do work with cleaned data!')
        return super(TestView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**Q1 : A front-developer can't work with {{ form }}. right?**

So I can change just example.html because it works properly if you set name attribute and type attribute correctly.

example.html

```
<form action="." method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="calorie">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

models.py

```
class Cereal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    calorie = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Q2 : I think it would be fine for a front developer to work with it if I change example.html above? right?**

Well, if my questions are all fine, It seems fine to use ModelForm and write html code instead of {{ form }} django template syntax. But if you use ModelChoiceField, it seems nasty. You set queryset argument and it shows with select widget on template. for example queryset reqsult is { A, B, C }. it will turn to like below

```
<select id="id_something" name="name of something">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

As i told you earlier, I don't want to use Django template syntax like {{ form }} as much as I can. so I am going to write like below instead.

views.py

```
render(request, "example.html", {queryset : something.objects.all()})
```

example.html

```
<select id="id_something" name="name of something">
    {% for element in queryset %}
    <option>{{ element }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**Q3: does this approach seem alright? Isn't it better way to use less Django template syntax when you use Django Form?**

well, I concluded that using DRF(Django RestFramework) is the best way to separate tasks for front-end and back-end developers independently. But In current situation I am facing, Template(html, css, js) is already made. I need to change it to use with Django framework. Front end developer will change little bit with the Template which is already made.

When I watched some pycon video in Youtube, some people said that Djang framework is kind of too much coupled.

I hope I can get Idea more efficiently to use Django Model form with front-end developer.

Thanks for reading. My question could be ridiculous for an expert. Please ask me again if it is not clear.

Comment: You can iterate over each form field and apply logic you need. What is the question here?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I am sad to hear that 'What is the question here?' as a comment. because recently I heard that several times. it proves that my question was very unclear. Well, so is there better way to work with Front-end developer? I understood that if you use more django template syntax, front end developer can work less independently. The solution i come up with is that I use model form and validate form data with generic formview, but not use {{ form }} template tag. That's why I wrote html code instead of writing one line {{form}}

Comment: You can always write `{% for field in form %} ... {% endfor %}` and inside this tag put `{{ field }}`, `{{ field.errors }}`, `{{ field.label_tag }}` — anything from the docs. `{{ form }}` or `{{ form.as_table }}` does the same thing but more generic.

Comment: In case of using ModelChoiceField, you need to {% for %} template tag anyway. I understood that it means front end developer can't work independently. But I thought that it is the best option I can come up with in current situation. because if you request and get data from API(if I build it with DRF), front-end developer need to get data by ajax or something. But template html is already all written and you are going to edit it.(in way to use Django framework). additionally front end developer will change some codes at the same time. so I wondered if it is better way? is it clear for you now?

Comment: if I just write {% for field in form %} ... {% endfor %}, how can another person( who doesn't know django ) can work with html code to change style or add js??

Comment: Well, templates in Django initially are designed to be used by FE devs. So, it's a good way for them to learn how to use them. You can try and explain them, that “JavaScript is not the only thing front end developers use” :)

Comment: You can add extra blocks in template like {% block extra_js %}{% endblock %} and add this block to your base template too, and FE devs will be able to add extra css/js there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126286/discussion-between-jayground-and-andrey-shipilov).